# Paraview Catalyst Build: If I download Base of the same version and set it as catalyst_source_dir while generating the source tree I get an error

Tags: paraview, pvpython

I'm trying to build Catalyst with an existing Superbuild of Paraview 4.1
I'm trying to generate the source tree as given in the wiki.
    cd /Catalyst
python catalyze.py -i Editions/Base/ -o

I don't know if I can find the source in the existing build if it is there. The files in the downloaded catalyst Base seems different from what is in Paraview installation.  Can I locate catalyst source in  an existing module?

Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that these catalyst editions are sort of 'stand-alone'. We don't have to mess with paraview installation but we should have most of what was needed as pre-requisits for paraview to build these. They consist of necessary files with cmakelists in order to build just by itself. It does not depend on ParaView. 
We don't have to generate the source tree as well. We only need to follow this step.
    cd 
    /cmake.sh  
The source_dir is the base files you downloaded and the build_dir is the empty build folder you create for the new build.
after this you need to run just 
    cd 
    make
While trying to run cmake.sh I encountered with 
    -- Found MPI_C: /opt/cray/craype/2.2.1/bin/cc 
    -- Found MPI_CXX: /opt/cray/craype/2.2.1/bin/CC 
    -- Could NOT find MPI_Fortran (missing:  MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES      MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_PATH) 
    CMake Error at VTK/CMake   /vtkTestingMPISupport.cmake:31 (message):
  MPIEXEC was empty.

I had to set MPI_Fortran to ftn location(similar to cc and CC) and   export MPIEXEC=mprun
to build it.